# Nested Resizables - How to destroy the parent and not the child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I have nested resizables using jQuery UI.

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>

$("#outer").resizable();
$("#inner").resizable();
```

I want to destroy the outer resizable, but not the inner.  Unfortuntely just doing this...

```
$("#outer").resizable("destroy");
```

...also breaks the inner resizable.  Currently the only way I can get this to work is by first destroying the child, then destroying the parent, then reinitializing the child.

```
$("#inner").resizable("destroy");
$("outer").resizable("destroy");
$("#inner").resizable();
```

While this is ok in a simplified example, in practice it is a headache, as my resizable init is complicated, and not easy to redo on the fly.

Does anyone know of any other workarounds / patches that would allow me to destroy the outer resizable and keep the inner resizable without having to also destroy and recreate the inner?

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to extend the resizable widget, and override its _destroy method.
Copy the original _destroy method to your extended widget and replace

```
find(".ui-resizable-handle")
```

with

```
children(".ui-resizable-handle")
```

The whole code is listed below:

```
$.widget( "ui.customResizable", $.ui.resizable, {
    _destroy: function() {

        this._mouseDestroy();

        var wrapper,
            _destroy = function(exp) {
                $(exp).removeClass("ui-resizable ui-resizable-disabled ui-resizable-resizing")
                    //The only place you need to change is replace find with children.
                    .removeData("resizable").removeData("ui-resizable").unbind(".resizable").children(".ui-resizable-handle").remove();
            };

        //TODO: Unwrap at same DOM position
        if (this.elementIsWrapper) {
            _destroy(this.element);
            wrapper = this.element;
            this.originalElement.css({
                position: wrapper.css("position"),
                width: wrapper.outerWidth(),
                height: wrapper.outerHeight(),
                top: wrapper.css("top"),
                left: wrapper.css("left")
            }).insertAfter( wrapper );
            wrapper.remove();
        }

        this.originalElement.css("resize", this.originalResizeStyle);
        _destroy(this.originalElement);

        return this;
    }
} );
```

Than use your extended widget rather than the original resizable.

```
$("#outer").customResizable();
$("#inner").customResizable();
$("#outer").customResizable("destroy");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
var inner_clone = $('#inner').clone(true);
$('#outer').resizable('destroy');
$('#inner').replaceWith(inner_clone);
```

Using .clone(true) *should* keep the resizable functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this already.  Unfortunately it doesn't work - my inner element(s) have a lot of bindings on them, which clone also seems to break.